# How to apply a formula to the only cells with a value in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a column of non-continuous data on E column and I want to apply a formula on the cells with a value only (where the data begins and ends is dynamic). I can only apply the formula on the entire array as on the code below. How can I fix it to only the cells with values be applied?

```vb
Sub wB_temp()
    
    Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(2).EntireColumn.Delete
    
    Dim arr0()      As Variant
    
    arr0 = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("D1:E4723").Value = arr0
    
    Rows(1).Insert
    Range("B1") = "=AVERAGE(B3:B4724)"
    Range("D1") = "prumer"
    Range("E2") = Range("B2").Value + "-prum"
    Range("E1") = ""
    
    Dim c           As Range
    Dim Lastrow     As Long
    Dim Avr         As Integer
    
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row
    Avr = Range("B1").Value
    
    For Each c In Range("E3:E" & Lastrow)
        c.Value = c.Value - Avr
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The string expression `"E3" & LastRow` would evaluate to something like `E31000` if `LastRow` is 1000, which I expect would be error 1004. Would `"E3:E" & LastRow` work as intended?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get what you want to do. I just want to point out that your two first lines of code will delete columns A and C from the original worksheet. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you again, guys, I have just edited my question, please check! Cheers!